# can delete manually a .ibd file and .frm file?

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.5, tablespaces

I have the following trouble in a mysql server database:

> 190919 17:35:30 [ERROR] Cannot find or open table abril2017/mexico from
>   the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the
>   table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
>   files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
>   of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
>   or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
>   doesn't support.
>
> See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
>   how you can resolve the problem.

Which is the secure way to resolve this problem?, fortunately is a database backup from the original. I have to run ALTER TABLE table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE or what should I do?

Regards.

Comment: "Fortunately is a database backup from the original." Perhaps /not/ so fortunate.  
If you created this database from a "backup" of your original database, then that "backup" does not contain everything in the original database - hence the errors - and, therefore, that backup is *useless*.  I would strongly recommend satisfying yourself that your backup method is actually working (i.e. take a backup, then restore it to another machine and make sure it works!)

Comment: I didnt explain at all, i mean this database was an extract from the records of  the activity from 2017 and this database is damaged, the "original" doesn't have this kind of trouble